# How to find why win32 dialog drawing hangs?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a win32 application which updates a lot of rectangles in a dialog quite fast. (now via `bitblt`(a bit of double buffering), before it was a different method - it doesnt matter).

And after random time passed - random dialog(from that application, with updating rectangles) just hangs on my PC. And by hanging i mean its redrawing hangs, if i push a menu button which popups something it works, but dialog doesnt shows anything just stays stuck. And it stays stuck until resized ! Or application restarted, ofc.

This only happens on my 'fast' PC with 3 desktops(controlled via different gpus).
My 'slow' laptop doesn't reproduce this, or maybe it would need more time to reproduce this(not a night, lets say) since its slower ?

I am really new in c++, windows dialogs programming - i may misused something or done something wrong. i checked everything i can, revisited microsoft tutorials on dialogs(and every drawing function) usage, checked everything - didnt quite found anything.

Maybe someone can offer me something smarter than disabling random functionality and waiting will it hang or not ? I would like to understand why it crashes(hangs), and why like this.

OS: Microsoft Windows 7 64
Compiler: Visual studio 2013

Addition: The debugger when stopped: Main thread shows only entrance of main dialog. DialogBox function, that's all. Ofc that thread is running all the other dialogs, but those dialogs are ran from main dialog called by DialogBox. Drawing is done by different thread, and it doesnt even notice that dialog hanged. The main thread doesn't 'hang' since other dialogs runs quite fine. and that 'hanged' dialog is fixed if resized, so strange.

Drawing by different thread means: dialogs are ran by main thread, other thread(actually couple of them and lower priority than other threads) is responsible for `biblt` and other drawing logic operations on those dialogs(since up to 600 rectangles can be updated up to 100Hz, it draws CPU quite well). I did addressed critical section problems and resources freeing when not used quite well but first thing i will do will be - rechecking those.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get an answer to this question without posting code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Debug it. Once it hangs, hard-break the debugger. As you have provided no code, the best you're going to get is wags (wild-ass-guesses).

Comment: Maybe someone had similar problems, or could think about why this could happen. Or maybe someone could offer a way to test this out, how to find a hang.
At this point all i need is guesses.

Comment: The debugger when stopped - main thread shows only entrance of main dialog. DialogBox function, that's all. Ofc that thread is running all the other dialogs, but those dialogs are ran from main dialog called by DialogBox.
Drawing is done by different thread, and it doesnt even notice that dialog hanged.
The main thread doesn't 'hang' since other dialogs runs quite fine. and that 'hanged' dialog is fixed if resized, so strange.

Comment: @Arnas - Dialogs are rarely drawn on.  Also, Windows API programming in general requires a lot of experience before undertaking things as you've described.  Any wrong move, and the program will not work correctly or consistently.  If you don't have the experience, then you won't know what to look for, regardless of how many tutorials you will read.  Better you post your code somewhere and let an experienced Windows programmer look at it.

Comment: can you show how "Drawing is done by different thread" looks like or describe it a little more in detail?

Comment: @Arnas You also mention "threads", but nowhere do you mention synchronization of those threads.  Mentioning that it only happens on your fast PC's but not on the slower one indicates thread synchronization issues.  Add that to the mix of not having experience in Windows dialogs, and you have a much bigger issue that needs real code to be shown.

Comment: When the UI is working, it sounds like un-freed resources/objects (e.g. device context, font, bitmap, etc.) Check whether everything in repaint part is correctly finished.

Comment: Drawing by different thread means: dialogs are ran by main thread, other thread(actually couple of them and lower priority than other threads) is responsible for biblt and other drawing logic operations on those dialogs(since up to 600 rectangles can be updated up to 100Hz, it draws CPU quite well). I did addressed critical section problems and resources freeing when not used quite well but first thing i will do will be - rechecking those.

application runs other operations in more seperate threads, but thats nothing to do i guess with our problem.

Comment: Accessing to Windows from a different thread that created them is asking for troubles, even if it is only drawing and you synchornize everything. You should draw from the working thread into a memory back-buffer and then notify the GUI thread, and then the GUI thread should do the blitblt to the window.

Comment: @rodrigo good, good point. I didn't tought about it. I saw microsoft saying that some functions must be ran from same thread. I can run bitblt by main thread(which runs dialogs), yes, i will do that. But i want a answer to a new question now, how should i synchronize bitblt from different thread with dialog thread so they would friendly cooperate if that is the problem ?

Comment: Why not use graphics library instead if you're doing so much drawing so often? From my experience bitblt is not fast and you should be careful using it. Can't say more without seeing your code though.

Comment: My suggestion is to use a memory bitmap as back-buffer. All the drawer threads will blt-write into it, and the main thread will blt-read from it. After drawing the threads will `PostMessage()` to notify the main thread. You can use a simple mutex to synchronize access to the BMP. You can also try doing unsynchronized blt-ing and see what happens, maybe if the rectangles do not overlap, it will just work...

Comment: @zoran404 yes, it's just it is my first c++ application(and its a biggie for a first one) and it is quite stable, i understood a lot memory management, critical sections, resources management problems while writing it. And as someone said - you're not supposed to write it cause you are not experienced enough is not quite right, how should i get experienced then ?
I did it threw bitblt cause that was the only way i knew. If you can give me similar examples via most universal graphics lib it would more than help me. Just sayin.

Comment: @rodrigo thanks, i were just thinking how to do that. Going to try.

Comment: @Arnas I don't think bitblt is actually meant for things like drawing a lot of objects, especially not doing it very often. It is possible to get it to do it, but it doesn't mean you should. If you're a beginner in c++ then SFML should be an easy library to start with, and it will surely be much faster than your current method. ( http://www.sfml-dev.org/ )

Comment: @rodrigo i done it your way, it works. I didnt had time to leave it for testing if it still hangs. but i already noticed that if you click and hold(without dragging) on your dialog window(border, to move whole window) it stops processing messages and redrawing. It just fills its messages queue till you move the clicked window or release it(release the click). That isn't quite nice, hmm.

Comment: Indeed, that is a known issue in the Windows internal message handling. You can see it even more clearly by keeping the caption buttons down. You can even make some (otherwise good programs) crash.

Comment: @rodrigo Where i could find more information about this issue ? How it is called ? it's quite interesting, already finding windows issues within 1st c++ application..
Does it stops whole thread from doing something or only message queues ? i could use somekind of same thread timers otherwise, then

Comment: Amas: I don't recall where I read it, but what happens is that when the caption or caption buttons is clicked the thread enters a private message loop (`GetMessage(..., WM_MOUSEFIRST, WM_MOUSELAST)`) until the mouse is unclicked. As consequence, IIRC, the window will process SendMessage'd messages, but not PostMessage'd ones nor timers nor redraws, those will be queued indefinitely. About what to do, my advice is just ignore the problem. Too difficult to do it right and if the user knows about this and does it, he deserves what he gets.

Comment: Ye, guessin im not supposed to use SendMessage for this kind of task.. ?! @rodrigo

Comment: @Arnas: No... `SendMessage()` between threads is tricky. Much better to use `PostMessage()`, and if the user is holding the minimize button, well... that's their fault.

Comment: @rodrigo i know you have helped me a lot and thanks for that, but i am still curious why sendmessage is so much worse than postmessage. Searched a bit on google, didnt found big nono or how-to's on using sentmessages... So i just used SendNotifyMessage instead of postmessage from different thread and i will see what will happen ^^ I understand that postmessages are lowest priority, that's why we do have such problems as u have mentioned.

Comment: @Arnas: `PostMessage()` sends a message to the thread queue, and it will eventually be returned by `GetMessage()` and processed. It is an asynchronous function. `SendMessage()` is synchronous: it will block the sending thread until the receiving one call one of several system calls (`GetMessage()`, `WaitMessage()`...); then the message is processed as a nested function call to the window procedure. The problem with `SendMessage()` is that it can easily result in dead-locks. Imagine two threads doing `SendMessage()` to each other at the same time!

Comment: @Arnas: `SendNotifyMessage()` behaves as `SendMessage()` if the sending thread is the same as the receiving one; and as `PostMessage()` if the sending thread is different from the receiving one. If you know the threads to be different, then there is no point in using `SendNotifyMessage()` instead of the better known `PostMessage()`.

Comment: @rodrigo well, SendNotifyMessage() doesnt reproduce our mentioned problem. since its priority is higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply not supposed to draw from other threads.

It is however safe for a single thread to draw to a bitmap (i.e. in memory), and then hand off that bitmap to the main thread for bitblt'ing. That can scale in the sense that you can have multiple threads prepare multiple bitmaps, and have the main thread bitblt each of those in turn.

Comment: That may be the problem, @rodrigo mentioned it first in the comments. Is there no way to 'correctly' synchronize drawing between 2 threads ? By the way microsoft isnt mentioning anything http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx about different threads... a bummer

Comment: @Arnas: That would be rather verbose, as they'd have to add that same restriction to each and every drawing function. The concept is known as `thread affinity`, and each window is associated with exactly one thread (but different windows obviously can be associated with different threads, even different processes)